# Find all $f(x)$ such that $f(gcd(x,y))=gcd(f(x),f(y))$

Tags: number-theory, functional-equations

How does one find all $f:\mathbb {Z} \rightarrow \mathbb {Z}$ that satisfies the following: $$f(gcd(x,y))=gcd(f(x),f(y))$$
I had suspected that there would be some results concerning this functional equation but was unable to find any.

It appears that the only solution for $f(x)$ would be $f(x)=cx^r$ for fixed integers $c,r$. However, I was unable to prove or disprove the statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: note that if $n|m$ then $f(n)|f(m)$

Comment: Will constant functions (e.g. $f(x)=1, \forall x$) be classified as bad examples?

Comment: @rtybase If you were trying to disprove my conjecture (as has been done below), it would be a bad example, I would think, as they are of the form $f(x)=cx^r$ where $r=0$. As just a example of this kind of function, however, it could be all right, in my opinion.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388228/sequences-that-commute-with-gcd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A combination of two solutions is again a solution. This does not help much with your class of functions, but wait.
2. Consider *any* [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function) that maps primes to a permutation thereof. Say, $2\mapsto3$, $3\mapsto2$, and the rest of primes map to themselves. This would do as well.

Comment: I'm not very experienced at math(or english), but what does maps primes to a permutation thereof mean? Could you give me a example?

Comment: I did give an example in the very next phrase. Consider a function such that $f(2)=3,\;f(3)=2$, for all other primes $f(p)=p$, and for composite values of argument use the multiplicative property.

Comment: Oh, I was asking for some other one. For example, is this a multiplicative function that maps primes to a permutation thereof? $f(2)=3,f(3)=5,f(5)=2017,f(2017)=2$ and for all other primes $f(p)=p$?

Comment: Yes, looks like this would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know that you'll find a "nice" general form.

$f(x) = c x^r$ works, as you noted. But so do the following, and many others.

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x$ is odd} \\
2 & \text{if $x$ is even}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
f(x) = \text{largest power of a fixed but otherwise arbitrary } p \in \mathbb N \text{ which divides } x
$$