# Increasing function $f(x)$ such that $f(\gcd(x,y))=\gcd(f(x),f(y))$

Tags: number-theory, functional-equations

This problem was largely inspired by this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631407/find-all-fx-such-that-fgcdx-y-gcdfx-fy).

There were many counterexamples given to the problem, such as a multiplicative function that maps primes to a permutation thereof.

However, if $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function, then what happens then?

It appears that if such $f(x)$ existed, then $f(1)=\gcd(f(1),f(y))$. This implies that $f(1)$ would have to divide $f(x)$ for any integer $x$. So one thing I tried doing was setting $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(1)}$. However, I was not able to proceed further.

So how does one find all $f(n)$ such that $\gcd(f(x),f(y))=f(\gcd(x,y))$, where $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function?

Note that all the counterexamples given were not increasing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you specify here _exactly_ what your question is, so that you don't have to refer us to a different question?

Comment: In either case, I believe $f(n)=\text{sgn}(n)(2^{|n|}-1)$ is an increasing sequence with asked property.

Comment: Or, sticking to natural numbers, $f(n)=F_n$, the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number.

Comment: Why doesn't $f(x)=2x$ work?

Comment: It appears that I lacked foresight in asking this problem. I did not completely think it through. For all $a,b$ where $a,b$ are coprime integers, $f(n)=a^n-b^n$ would be such a solution. In fact, I think they are called strong divisibility sequences.